# Finding minimum of value $x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2$

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-optimization

> Suppose $x,y,z,t$ are real numbers which holds for these equations:
> numbers:
>
> ${ \begin{cases}{x^2+6y+2t=2} \\ {y^2+2t+y=-14} \\
>  {z^2+4x+2y=-27} \\  {t^2+2z+y=5}\end{cases} }$
>
> What is the minimum
> value of $x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2$ ?
> $$1)12\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad2)18\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad3)34\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad4)38\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad5)\text{none}$$
> $$$$

I added all the equations together:

$$x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2+4x+10y+4t+2z=-34$$
$$(x^2+4x+4)+(y^2+10y+25)+(z^2+2z+1)+(t^2+4t+4)=0$$
$$(x+2)^2+(y+5)^2+(z+1)^2+(t+2)^2=0$$

Since each squares are non negative, each of them should be zero, therefore $x=-2,\quad y=-5,\quad z=-1,\quad t=-2.$

But when I put these numbers in the original equations neither of them holds for the equations. so can we  conclude there is not exist such real numbers $x,y,z,t$ that holds for the equations and therefore the answer is $5)\text{none}$. am I right?

Comment: WolframAlpha also confirms that no real solutions exist, https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Bx%5E2%2B6y%2B2t%3D2%7D%2C%7By%5E2%2B2t%2By%3D-14%7D%2C%20%7Bz%5E2%2B4x%2B2y%3D-27%7D%2C%20%7Bt%5E2%2B2z%2By%3D5%7D

Comment: **Meta-cheating** I question what the point would be of posing such a question.  **To the OP**: is it plausible that you made a mistake with one or more of the equations (i.e. coefficients), and that therefore there is at least one real solution, if not an infinity of solutions?

Comment: @user2661923 No I checked the original question I typed it here correctly.

Comment: You did a pretty smooth job by completing the squares, this solves the exercise in no time. So yes, you can confidently answer 5) none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have both checked your solution, and confirmed it via WolframAlpha. No real solutions exist for this system of equations, and hence, the answer should be none.

Here is the [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Bx%5E2%2B6y%2B2t%3D2%7D%2C%7By%5E2%2B2t%2By%3D-14%7D%2C%20%7Bz%5E2%2B4x%2B2y%3D-27%7D%2C%20%7Bt%5E2%2B2z%2By%3D5%7D) to the WolframAlpha computation.